# There is no way to integrate real-valued functions in a coordinate independent way on a manifold

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

In Lee's ISM, an example is given to show that there is no way to integrate real-valued functions in a coordinate independent way.

> Suppose $C\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a closed ball, and $f:C\to \mathbb R$ is the constant function $1$. Then 
>   $$\int_C f~dV=\text{Vol}(C)$$ is clearly not invariant under coordinate transformations.

But why? The RHS is clearly invariant under coordinate transformations. But I feel like the LHS is also invariant under coordinate transformations by the definition of Riemann integral or Lebesgue integral. When $f$ is a constant, then $\int_C f~dV=\text{measure of}~C=\text{Vol}(C)$. Could anybody tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: The RHS is *not* at all invariant under coordinate transformations. Even in the case of linear maps, if we take the transformation $\phi\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ given by $\phi(x)=2x$, then $\text{vol}(\phi(C)) = 2^n\text{vol}(C)$. In general, review the change of variables theorem.

Comment: Does the Gaussian curvature of a surface count as a real valued function?

Comment: @snulty: Yes, Gaussian curvature is a real-valued function, and it can be integrated in a coordinate-invariant way _on a Riemannian manifold_. The full sentence before the one the OP quoted in my book says: "First, observe that there is no way to integrate real-valued _functions_ in a coordinate-invariant way on a manifold, at least without adding further structure such as a Riemannian metric."

Comment: @JackLee thanks for your comment. I didn't check the quoted passage, I just commented on what I had read. Thanks, and I'll have a look at your book, I've heard good things. Cheers.